# get VGG16 model to acceptable accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to get VGG16 model to acceptable accuracy but I can't get it above .3
here's the model

```
def VGG16():

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(224,224,3),filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2),name='vgg16'))

    model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))

    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1'))

    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2'))

    model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax', name='output'))

    return model
```

```
opt = SGD(learning_rate=1e-6, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

some answers here suggested changing the number of neurons in the fully connected layers to 4096 (originally used 256 and 128), using SGD instead of Adam, increasing the number of epochs (tried 50, 100 and 200) and the batch size (tried 64 and 128) but I can't get it above .3 and usually it's .2.
parameters I used in the best result are

```
fully connected neurons 4096
optimizer SGD
learning rate e-6
epochs 100
batch size 128
```

**edit** dataset used https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nodoubttome/skin-cancer9-classesisic

Answer (score 1):

you did not show the data for the model training but I suspect your model will be very prone to over fitting. You need to add some dropout layers and some regularization.
After your flatten layer type the following

```
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 ))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu') )

model.add(Dropout(rate=.4, seed=123), name='dropout'))

model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax', name='output'))
```

it would be helpful if you provide the model training data as well

Comment: I edited the post to add the training data. images have many different sizes and I resized all of them to 224*224 to use them in the model